# Spring Boot startup throws Exception: No thread-bound request found for request scoped bean

Tags: spring, proxy, scope, jersey

I'm trying to build a Proof-of-Concept using Spring Boot (1.3.5) with Jersey.  My pom has the `spring-boot-starter-jersey` artifact listed as a dependency.

With only singleton beans defined, it works fine.  However, I've now tried to inject request-scoped beans into a singleton bean and am running into the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.jndi': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:355) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(CglibAopProxy.java:687) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:637) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at $java.util.Properties$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1a020092.size(<generated>) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.createInitialContext(JndiTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.getContext(JndiTemplate.java:103) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:85) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:106) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.lookup(AbstractRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.refreshHome(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:121) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.refreshHome(SimpleRemoteSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:162) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:108) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:41) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

According to what I read, I need to enable the `RequestContextListener`, which I have done, but it hasn't made any difference:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(name="jndi")
    @Scope(scopeName=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Properties getJNDIContext(){
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces" );
        p.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp://localhost:1099");
        p.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory");
        p.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"test" );
        p.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"12345678" );
        return p;
    }

    @Bean
    public FactoryBean<?> getAthleteManagerFactory(@Qualifier("jndi") Properties p){
        SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean factory = new SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean();
        String beanName = "zone.jndi.ejb3.RemoteAthleteManager";
        factory.setJndiName(beanName);
        factory.setBusinessInterface(AthleteManager.class);
        factory.setJndiEnvironment(p);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean 
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
        return new RequestContextListener();
    } 

}
```

And my controller is fairly simple:

```
@Component
@Path("/athlete")
public class AthleteController {

    @Autowired
    private AthleteManager athleteManager;

    ....
    ....
}
```

I suspect the error is that the factory is trying to instantiate the object using a proxied request-scoped bean to inject into my Controller, and the request scope doesn't yet exist.

Is there a way to resolve this problem? I would have expected the `proxyMode` to handle the issue, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.  I get similar (albeit slightly different) exception stack traces with or without the `proxyMode` enabled.

If I mark my factory as Lazy, it still doesn't make a difference as Spring needs to instantiate it (and its object) in order to autowire my controller class.

Is there any way to do this?  My need is for a filter to override the credentials in the `getJNDIContext()` properties object at each call.

Comment: Given the stack trace, A JNDI lookup is done at bean initialization time in order to get the home interface of your remote EJB, and since the properties used to do the JNDI lookup are request-scoped, and this is done at initialization time, there is no request and the properties are thus not usable. I don't really understand why you would need that bean to be request-scoped. Apparently, even if that worked, the JNDI lookup would already have been done when yoyr filter executes, and changing the credentials would be useless.

Comment: @jbnizet thanks. That's somewhat the conclusion I came to as well but was hoping for better news. My issue is that I need the credentials from the request for the JNDI invocation. So I'm in a little chicken/egg dance here. I'm hoping too be able to extract request credentials in a filter and update my properties object at that time. Then, when it comes time to actually execute my remote ejb, the appropriate creds would be in place.  I'm open to suggestions to a workflow that would allow this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to my issue, although I don't particularly like it.  For starters, I need to delay the JNDI bean lookup/initialization from startup so that the container doesn't try to populate the JNDI properties until they are actually available (only at the Request time).  I also noticed that I am unable to scope the JNDI to the request scope, and consequently have to look it up every time (or the authentication credentials may be incorrect).

```
@Bean(name="jndi")
@Scope(scopeName=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public Properties getJNDIContext(){
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces" );
    p.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp://localhost:1099");
    p.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory");
    return p;
}

@Bean
public FactoryBean<?> getLoginManagerFactory(@Qualifier("jndi") Properties p){
    return getEjbFactoryBean(LoginManager.class, p );
}

/**
 * Helper method to setup the factory
 * @param clazz
 * @param jndi
 * @return
 */
private SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean getEjbFactoryBean(Class clazz, Properties jndi){
    SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean factory = new SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean();
    // need to delay lookup since security params are only available in a request thread
    factory.setLookupHomeOnStartup(false);
    // refresh home in case EJB server is restarted
    factory.setRefreshHomeOnConnectFailure(true);
    // do not cache - need to lookup every time due to changing security params.  They are only set upon initial bean lookup
    factory.setCacheHome(false);
    // set the JNDI properties  
    factory.setJndiEnvironment(jndi);

    String beanName = REMOTE_EJB_PREFIX + clazz.getSimpleName();
    factory.setJndiName(beanName);
    factory.setBusinessInterface(clazz);
    return factory;
}
```

Finally, I set up a filter to specify my credentials on every request:

```
@Provider
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired  @Qualifier("jndi")
    private Properties userCreds;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        // extract username/password from basic auth
        String[] auth = decode( requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) );
        userCreds.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, auth[0] );
        userCreds.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, auth[1] );
    }
}
```

Conceptually, this works, but it is very inefficient.  I would like to find a solution that allows me to do the same, but at least scope my bean at the request level, so that it isn't retrieved every time.